# copy and paste only filter cells from one excel to other excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm stuck with a problem when I try to copy filtered cells from one excel file and paste it onto another file. I am using a macro call to get data where I try to fix this given code. It is working when I try to copy cells that are not filtered. Only I get a problem when I try to copy the visible cells only. I would like to ask for help to fix this problem.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim lrCD As Long
    Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim SourceWB As Workbook
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim ASheet As Worksheet
    fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Seleziona il file da aprire")

    'Sets the variables:
    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ASheet = ActiveSheet
    Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath)  'Modify to match

    'Copies each sheet of the SourceWB to the end of original wb:
    For Each WS In SourceWB.Worksheets
        WS.Copy after:=WB.Sheets(WB.Sheets.Count)
    Next WS

        SourceWB.Close savechanges:=False
        Set WS = Nothing
        Set SourceWB = Nothing

    WB.Activate
    ASheet.Select

    Set ASheet = Nothing
    Set WB = Nothing

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    lastrow = Worksheets(4).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).End(xlUp).Row


    For i = 3 To lastrow
        Worksheets(4).Cells(i, 16).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        erow = Worksheets("CFF").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets(4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues = Worksheets("CFF").Cells(erow + 1, 2)
        Worksheets(4).Cells(i, 16).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        Worksheets(4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues = Worksheets("CFF").Cells(erow + 1, 3)
        Worksheets(4).Cells(i, 15).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        Worksheets(4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues = Worksheets("CFF").Cells(erow + 1, 4)
        Worksheets(4).Cells(i, 12).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        Worksheets(4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues = Worksheets("CFF").Cells(erow + 1, 5)
        Worksheets(4).Cells(i, 13).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        Worksheets(4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues = Worksheets("CFF").Cells(erow + 1, 6)
        Worksheets(4).Cells(i, 18).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        Worksheets(4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues = Worksheets("CFF").Cells(erow + 1, 1)
    Next i

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

     Sheets(4).Select
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete

     Sheets(2).Select           

End Sub
```

Comment: Your syntax looks off - `Worksheets(4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues = Worksheets("CFF").Cells(erow + 1, 2)` is not valid. What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: I have 2 different execl file one call 'CFF' where i have to paste some specific range from another excel sheet .the another sheet (4) is a filtered list file .so in this point i can't copy those visible cells which i already filtered and paste it to my worksheet (cff)

Comment: hi SJR, could you help me? or is there anyone who could help me. i really need to solve this urgent.

Comment: You haven't described the specific problem you are having with the code you've posted. There is plenty of material online about VBA and autofilter. As already stated, you have some syntax issues to start with.

Comment: Hi SJR my problem when i call the macro it open the worksheet from my desktop but can't copy and paste onto my desiered worksheet (CFF) and don't show me error.it is strange problem i have found.after saw your advice i try to little change to my paste method even nothing wokring        here it is :     

Worksheets(4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(i, 19).Copy
Worksheets("CFF").Cells(erow + 1, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code using F8 to see what's going on?

Comment: Yes i tried it's show me public sub method_commandbutton is not working.

Comment: hi ,is there anyone who could help me , still now i am stuck on the same  problem.